# The smallest topology in $\mathbb C$ in which every singleton set is closed

Tags: general-topology

> Let $\tau$  be the ***smallest*** topology on $\mathbb C$  such that every singleton set under $\tau$ is closed. Then which of the following is true ?
>
> $1.(\mathbb C,\tau) \text{ is  not Hausdorff}.$
>
> $2.(\mathbb C,\tau) \text{ compact }$
>
> $3.(\mathbb C,\tau) \text{ connected }.$
>
> $4. \mathbb Z \text{ is dense in } (\mathbb C,\tau).$

All $4$ options are  correct if I consider this to be the **co-finite topology on the Complex numbers.**  But I do not know what the **smallest** topology would be. It won't be the discrete one but what other options do we have here ?

Please discuss.Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all, notice that nothing about this problem is particular to $\Bbb C$; you can replace it with any infinite set whatsoever (and then $\Bbb Z$ is replaced by your favorite infinite subset).

It does turn out to be true that the smallest suitable topology is the co-finite topology (so awesome that you know the answers for that topology already!). One needs to show that any topology in which every singleton set is closed contains the co-finite topology. So let $\tau$ be such a topology. Can you show that any set $U$ that is open in the co-finite topology must also be open in $\tau$, just using the properties of topologies (such as the finite intersection property) and the one extra thing we know about $\tau$?

Comment: yes I can show that. thank you.